# Deleting all Docker images from a repository

Tags: docker

I want to delete all Ubuntu images from Docker. Here is what docker images shows:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
nginx               test                b585568733c7        3 weeks ago         93.46 MB
ubuntu              14.04               ce76de2e871b        4 weeks ago         188 MB
ubuntu              12.04               583364cb662d        4 weeks ago         138 MB
tommylau/ocserv     latest              26d1014b5930        5 weeks ago         145.6 MB
nginx               1.7.11              520f1dbba9d6        12 months ago       93.44 MB
```

How can I delete ubuntu:14.04 and ubuntu:12.04 with a single command?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q ubuntu)
```

`-q` lists only the image id, and `docker images -q ubuntu` lists all `ubuntu` images' ids.

Comment: Awesome. I spent half an hour trying to figure this out.